# Angular4 component call jquery

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 4. Inside a component.html file, there is checkbox. The checkbox is required to call a `Jquery` function `iCheck` to change its outlook. However, I put the script under the component, it cannot trigger the script. May I know if I need to call the `iCheck` `jquery` function inside the `component.ts`? Or simply, can I call the `$(document).ready(function ())` under `component.ts`. Please advise. Thanks.

```
<input type="checkbox">

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('input[type="checkbox"]').iCheck({
          checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat-blue',
          radioClass: 'iradio_flat-blue'
      });
    });
</script>
```

Best regards,
Ken

Comment: what error comes in console? and its component.ts file not .js

Comment: "It does not work" is not really a helpful description

Comment: I have change it to "it cannot trigger the script"

Comment: Hi Manish, the script cannot run, no error shows in the console

Comment: Hi Manish, yes, it should be ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For accessing jquery in Typescript.First you need to install using npm as follows.

**npm install jquery --save**

After that go to ./angular-cli.json file at the root of your Angular CLI project folder, and find the scripts: [] property, and include the path to jQuery as follows
**“scripts”: [ “../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js” ]**
After including jQuery stop running your Angular CLI application and then re run it using ng serve.

Now to use jQuery anywhere in your application, all you have to do is to import it as follows in app.component.ts file.
**import * as $ from ‘jquery’;**

After this you can use jquery for you checkbox click event like that
in your HTML code add click event `<input type="checkbox" (click)="onClick()">`
where onClick() is the method you have to create in Component.ts like below

```
onClick()
{
//in this method you can put your jquery code
 $('input[type="checkbox"]').iCheck({
          checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat-blue',
          radioClass: 'iradio_flat-blue'
      });
}
```